# Integral with bounded function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

If $m$ is a finite measure on $X$, for which bounded measurable functions $g$ do we have the following: if $f$ is integrable on $X$ and $\int_{X}fdm = 0$ then $\int_{X} fg dm = 0$?

Maybe I'm not understanding something here, but if $g$ is bounded, let $|g| \leq M$ don't we have $$0 =(-M)\int_X fdm = \int_X f (-M)dm \leq \int_X fg dm \leq \int_{X} f M dm = M\int_Xfdm= 0$$ 
and therefore we don't need anything else for $g$? And the finite measure hypothesis also doesn't seem to be important. If someone sees why this is wrong please say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=[0,2\pi]$ with the Lebesgue measure and let $f(x)=\sin(x)$. It is easy to see that $g=f$ does not satisfies your claim.

Comment: Thanks, I see now, the equality doesn't hold if $f$ is negative... Any idea about what should $g$ be?